# Integrate a telegram bot developed in php in a telegram channel

Tags: telegram-bot, php-telegram-bot

I have a channel and I want users (subscribed to the channel) to be able to interact with the bot.
Obviously a user can't send message in the channel, but he can interact with the bot, so he can send it messages.

Is there a way to use a telegram bot in a telegram channel?

I tried to add the bot in a test channel but I can't interact with him